# What does `&` mean in vim map

Tags: vim

In some map, I found an difference by `:imap`.

Some maps begin `*`, whether some maps begin `&`.

What is the meaning?

Comment: Please edit in the exact `imap` that you wish to know about. The question should be self-contained, without relying on external sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `:help map-listing`:

> ```
> Just before the {rhs} a special character can appear:
>     *       indicates that it is not remappable
>     &       indicates that only script-local mappings are remappable
>     @       indicates a buffer-local mapping
> ```